# json.length() associative array format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I work with an API that give me some JSON.

When I retrieve 10 or less element, my JSON is formated as this :

```
[
{"data":"data1","data2":"data3"},
{...},
{"data":"data1","data2":"data3"}
]
```

**BUT**, when I retrieve more than 10 element, json_encode format my datas like this :

```
{"0":[{"data":"data1","data2":"data3"}],
"...":[{...}],
"12":[{"data":"data1","data2":"data3"}]
}
```

This JSON is valid in both case, but I can't make a `myJson.length` in JS on the second JSON.

How can I make work, and if I can't, what can I do to test the length of my JSON array ?

Thanks :)

Comment: In the second case, you have an object, not an array.

Comment: for second JSON, Object.keys(data).length , @Quentin is right

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. `json_encode` correctly produces a JSON array when I have a PHP array with more than 10 items in it. https://www.evernote.com/l/AAP9pO9qWgxMSLmeidDDcU4E0jCWbd4Lwrw

Comment: @Quentin Isn't it due to php json_encode method ? is the return is different because of that ?

Comment: @Jiedara — I used the PHP `json_encode` method (you can see that in the link I provided), so no, it isn't.

Comment: @Quentin That's odd, because my php array before json_encode have the same format before json_encode and are totally different after ...
Maybe is a char hidden in my datas.

Comment: The reason `json_encode` would return the latter format is if not all keys are continuously ordered numerical. That means you're somehow futzing up the keys in the array before you encode it. Your fix should be there, not on the Javascript side.

Comment: @deceze There it is ! It seem to do the trick. I do some test, and I'll be glad to upvote your answer if you made one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `json_encode` would return the latter format is if not all keys are continuously ordered numerical. The reason being that PHP only has one array type, but this maps to either a JSON `[]` array or `{}` object, depending on what keys it contains. That means you're somehow futzing up the keys in the array before you encode it. Your fix should be there, not on the Javascript side.

Comment: That's it, `unset()` datas before making a `json_encode()` force PHP to make an object.

Answer (score 0):

The second JSON isn't in fact a JSON array but a JSON object, you could do as following to get an array of all the keys in the object and then get the length from that:

```
Object.keys(JSON).length
```

Comment: … this does, however, require that you determine you have an object first and may not correctly preserve the order of the data. You should fix the PHP that is generating the object so it generates an array instead.

Comment: Agreed with @Quentin, dealing with the JSON object is working around the real problem, which is the API returning unstable data.